# jfrog-xray fails to start (fresh installation)

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

I'm in the process of installing jfrog-xray (version 2.8.6) on redhat.

I have followed the installation instructions for installing to bare metal (compared to docker) and the install seems to have gone fine.

However, when trying to start all the services, it appears that none of them get off the ground.

The following is what the ./xray.sh satus command produces:

```
Checking Xray services...
=========================
Checking xray-server...                           grep: account: No such file or directory
grep: is: No such file or directory
grep: currently: No such file or directory
grep: not: No such file or directory
grep: available.: No such file or directory
The process appears to be dead but pidfile still exists
Checking xray-indexer...                          grep: account: No such file or directory
grep: is: No such file or directory
grep: currently: No such file or directory
grep: not: No such file or directory
grep: available.: No such file or directory
The process appears to be dead but pidfile still exists
Checking xray-persist...                          grep: account: No such file or directory
grep: is: No such file or directory
grep: currently: No such file or directory
grep: not: No such file or directory
grep: available.: No such file or directory
The process appears to be dead but pidfile still exists
Checking xray-analysis...                         grep: account: No such file or directory
grep: is: No such file or directory
grep: currently: No such file or directory
grep: not: No such file or directory
grep: available.: No such file or directory
The process appears to be dead but pidfile still exists
```

when i look at the journal entry for xray-server (sudo journalctl -u xray-server) I get the following output:

```
-- Logs begin at Sun 2019-06-09 08:14:36 AEST, end at Thu 2019-06-13 13:55:13 AEST. --
Jun 08 22:15:32 server systemd[1]: Starting LSB: xray-server...
Jun 08 22:15:32 server xray-server[5621]: Starting service as user xray...
Jun 08 22:15:34 server su[5626]: (to xray) root on none
Jun 08 22:15:38 server xray-server[5621]: Service started
Jun 08 22:15:38 server systemd[1]: Started LSB: xray-server.
Jun 12 15:39:27 server systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: xray-server...
Jun 12 15:39:27 server xray-server[13836]: Service not running
Jun 12 15:39:27 server systemd[1]: xray-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 12 15:39:27 server systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: xray-server.
Jun 12 15:39:27 server systemd[1]: Unit xray-server.service entered failed state.
Jun 12 15:39:27 server systemd[1]: xray-server.service failed.
```

Comment: When I read those status lines it looks to me like something has written "account is currently not available" in the pid file for each service. (Possibly with "ERROR:" or something in front.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did an uninstall, then reinstall, and it is fine.
I think the issue is we did a reboot of the server too soon after the install (almost straight away) so the services may have been in the middle of doing something.

Answer (score 0):

Install grep on your machine and try

Comment: Unfortunately grep is already installed. I believe grep is the command generating that particular line.